# Objective-C: How to avoid unintended calls to private superclass methods with identical name?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to avoid duplicate code in various `-(id)init` flavors of a class, i.e. `init`, `initWithFrame`, `initWithCoder`, etc. by defining a private method that is named `commonConstruct`.

This method does the heavy lifting common to all init method flavors and gets called by the `init` constructor.

The issue i have now is that in derived classes, using the same naming convection for the initializer helper ("commonConstruct") the base class will call the derived class's `commonConstruct`, though it is `invisible`, i.e. declared in the `.m` file, not in the `.h` file.

However, the runtime finds the overloaded commonConstruct and executes that instead of its own member function.

Is there any other way than using a different name for the initializer helper in each subclass ?

In other words: Is there a way of making `Objective-C` member functions that are "non-virtual", i.e. don't have late (runtime) but compile-time binding?

Comment: where is `commonConstruct` defined?

Comment: commonConstruct is defined in each class's @implementation section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no good compiler-enforced way to do this.  Methods are always “virtual” and there is no enforcement of “private” methods.

The common solution is to embed the class name in the method name, thus:

```
@implementation Thing

- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self Thing_commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithArg:(NSObject *)arg {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self Thing_commonInit];
        [self doSomethingWithArg:arg];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)Thing_commonInit {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Rob Mayoff's solution (which I use as well) you could use a static C function:

```
@implementation Thing
{
    id _privateIvar;
}

- (id)init
{
    return commonInit([super init], nil);
}

- (id)initWithArgument:(id)argument
{
    return commonInit([super init], argument);
}

static Thing *commonInit(Thing *self, id argument)
{
    if (self == nil)
        return nil;
    self->_privateIvar = argument;
    return self;
}

@end
```

Static functions don't emit symbols, so there are no possible conflicts. You can name all of your common initializers `commonInit`.

Comment: That's a good idea. The only drawback is that you need to pass the instance pointer around. Benefit is that you don't create message table entries that you don't need.

Comment: @AraschHonarbacht Yes, the instance pointer is of course needed to do the initialization of the instance. The only difference when using an instance method is that it's implicitly passed (along with the selector) instead of explicitly as with the C function.