# How to call method in same class

Tags: objective-c

I have a superclass, SuperClassYeh and a subclass, SubClassYeh. I have method `inheritTest` in SuperClassYeh and I override `inheritTest` in SubClassYeh. I start the program running by calling method `testSuperAndSelf` in SubClassYeh. This method would call another method, `fromYEH` in SuperClassYeh. In `fromYEH`, I would like to call `inheritTest` in SuperClassYeh. How do I do that? Using `[self inheritTest]` calls the `inheritTest` in SubClassYeh, not SuperClassYeh. 
Here's the code fragment to start the whole thing running

```
SubClassYeh *testing = [[SubClassYeh alloc] init];
[testing testSuperAndSelf];
```

Here's the code fragment for SuperClassYeh

```
- (void) fromYEH
{
    [self inheritTest]; //Calls the inheritTest in SubClassYeh, not SuperClassYeh
}

- (void) inheritTest
{
    NSLog(@"Testing Indicator. Inside SuperClassYEH inheritTest");
}
```

Here's the code fragment for SubClassYeh

```
- (void) inheritTest
{
    NSLog(@"Testing Indicator. Inside SubClassYeh inheritTest");
}

- (void) testSuperAndSelf
{
    [super fromYEH];  
}
```

Comment: just one question. why do you need to do this? it is a bit strange behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Instead of calling `[super fromYeh]`in `testSuperAndSelf`, change the receiver to   the superclass. Use `[[[[SubClassYeh superclass] alloc] init] fromYEH]`. Inside method `fromYEH`, the `inheritTest` of `SuperClassYEH` would be called.
Here is the code fragment for method `testSuperAndSelf` in `SubClassYeh`. Other codes remain the same.

```
- (void) testSuperAndSelf
{
    [[[[SubClassYeh superclass] alloc] init] fromYEH];  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

*You can't,* and this is the intended behaviour of inheritance in Objective-C.

If `self` is an instance of `SubClassYeh`, then

```
[self inheritTest]
```

calls the `SubClassYeh` implementation of `inheritTest` (if there is one),
no matter from where that message is sent (subclass or superclass).

The only difference between `[super fromYEH]` and `[self fromYEH]` is that the lookup
for the "fromYEH" message starts at the superclass, but it does not change the fact
that `self` is an instance of `SubClassYeh`.

And you cannot prevent a method from being overriden in Objective-C
(see [How to avoid superclass methods getting overridden by sub class in objective - c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864273/how-to-avoid-superclass-methods-getting-overridden-by-sub-class-in-objective-c) or other Q&A's about that topic).

The only thing that you can do in the superclass is to choose method names 
that are not overriden *accidentally*, e.g. by prefixing the method name
with the class name, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17209309/1187415.

Answer (score 0):

If you can call `[super fromYEH]` from SubClassYeh, what is the problem in calling `[super inheritTest]` the same way?

Comment: It doesn't work. You cannot call [super inheritTest] in fromYeh, which is already in SuperClassYeh.

Comment: Can you not call [super inheritTest]; from testSuperAndSelf method?

Answer (score 0):

Even it is a quite strange behavior, you can try something like this(didn't test it, actually)

```
- (void) fromYEH
{
    bool isSubClass = [self isKindOfClass:[SubClassYeh class]];
    if(isSubClass == YES)
    {
        [super performSelector:@selector(inheritTest)];
    }
    else
    {
        [self inheritTest];
    }
}
```

Anyway, even if this code will really do the trick, I still think that this is very bad practice.

---

**EDIT:**

Checked this in XCode. It will not do the trick =) So upvoted Martin's answer =)

Comment: Some remarks: 1) `[super respondsToSelector:...]` does not do what you think. It returns true even if `self`, but not the superclass implements that method. - 2) `isBaseClass` will always be YES, you probably meant `isMemberOfClass`? - 3) `[super inheritTest]` does not compile, you would have to use `performSelector`. - 4) What if `self` is an instance of a sub-sub-class?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Made several changes. And in this case there is a chance to get "unrecognized selector" exception. Also, it is true, that this method will work wrong in case of sub-sub-class.

Comment: Sorry to keep badgering you, but `[super performSelector:...]` does also not work as you might think.

Comment: Not a problem at all in such a badgering =) , just you've forced me to go to my mac, open xcode and make sure, that you are right =) I will not delete my post to prevent someone other from trying this method =)

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record...

What you want to do isn't as difficult as you think, if you look at it from a different perspective.

All you have to do is define a C function and call that.

```
- (void) fromYEH
{
    inheritTest(self); //Calls the inheritTest() in SuperClassYeh
}

void inheritTest(SuperClassYeh *self)
{
    NSLog(@"Testing Indicator. Inside SuperClassYEH inheritTest");
}    

- (void) inheritTest
{
    inheritTest(self);
}
```

(I love the names... ;)